# Can`t install handbrake-js using npm on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, handbrake-js

I am trying to install all dependencies of a project, which inclues - "handbrake-js": "^1.1.8".

Here`s the error I get on npm-install :

```
> handbrake-js@1.1.9 postinstall C:\uploader\uploader\node_modules\handbrake-js
> node scripts/install.js

fetching: http://sourceforge.net/projects/handbrake/files/0.9.9/HandBrake-0.9.9-x86_64-Win_CLI.zip/download
extracting: unzipped\HandBrakeCLI.exe
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: invalid signature: 0x6f64213c
    at C:\uploader\uploader\node_modules\unzip\lib\parse.js:59:13
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)                                                                                     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! handbrake-js@1.1.9 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the handbrake-js@1.1.9 postinstall script.
```

I tried to install handbrake-js globally using : npm install -g handbrake-js .
But then I get this error:

```
fetching: http://download.handbrake.fr/releases/1.0.7/HandBrakeCLI-1.0.7-win-x86_64.zip
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:

    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! handbrake-js@3.0.3 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the handbrake-js@3.0.3 postinstall script.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this will happen if node thinks you're on a 32bit platform, it tries to download a file that doesn't exist -- since you're 64bit (right?) -- run node -p "process.arch" you'll see it reporting 32, reinstall node, run again and should say x64 - then the install command will work